# CSS: Line-through with a color different from the text color?

Tags: html, css, strikethrough

I’d like to have gray text with a red strike-through, but this style doesn’t work:

```
color: #a0a0a0;
text-decoration: line-through 3px red;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can simulate the desired effect with two nested elements, e.g.:

```css
        span.inner {
            color: green;
        }
        span.outer {
            color: red;
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }
```

```html
<span class="outer">
    <span class="inner">foo bar</span>
</span>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinfunk/b2ztqLr3/)

Answer (score 22):

With no extra DOM (but may not work for some layouts for obvious reasons):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .strikethrough {
        position: relative;
    }

    .strikethrough:before {
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
</style>

<span class="strikethrough">Foo Bar</span>
```

[A jsfiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tA4qs/)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this does not work well for multi-line inline elements. Only the first line will be decorated.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way of looking at the meaning of the CSS2 specification; and that is the outer text-decoration will set the color of the "line-through" and text, but an inner color declaration (in a 'span' tag) can be used to reset the text color.

```
<p style="text-decoration:line-through;color:red">
<span style="color:#000">
The "line-through" and "color" are declared in 'p', and the inner 'span' 
declares the correct color for the text.
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This actually should get more upvotes, as it does what the OP wants with minimum added markup, and *works for multi-line texts also*.

Comment: Fantastic solution!

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to make a line-through with a different color. It will be in the color you define with property `color`.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props

**EDIT**:

what came into my mind is to use a background-image with a 1px * 1px color dot in the color you like.

CSS:

```
.fakeLineThrough {
  background-image: url(lineThroughDot.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="fakeLineThrough">the text</span>
```

Comment: nope, the line will be behind the text.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS2 specs says

> The color(s) required for the text decoration must be derived from the 'color' property value of the element on which 'text-decoration' is set. The color of decorations must remain the same even if descendant elements have different 'color' values

I guess that means that you can't do it that way.

A workaround could be using some kind of border, and lifting it?